# Where can i find $PS that looks like this?

Tags: prompt, iterm2

[image]
I have installed a Dracula Theme(https://draculatheme.com/iterm/) on my iTerm2, however, it doesn't seem to come with $PS parameters that give the exact same look for the prompt text with icons. I searched the internet to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $PS parameters you see is a theme of Oh-My-Zsh.

Use command:`zsh --version` to see if you get zsh shell in your computer.

If it comes out the version, you have Zsh already.

Use command line to install Oh-My-Zsh:(You can go to the official website to geti the command line)

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

***Oh-My-Zsh is a tool to help you config Zsh.***

Use command:`chsh -s /bin/zsh` to change your shell from Bash or other shells to Zsh.

Restart your terminal.

You will got Dracula Theme as you see in the picture, because it uses the default theme of Oh-My-Zsh.

You will find more themes of Oh-My-Zsh to change the $PS parameters. And you will learn how to edit the configuration files to change the $PS parameters.

Comment: Sorry! You may use the Oh-My-Zsh theme as the author of dracula published:(https://draculatheme.com/zsh/)